# How to configure Azure Blob storage with AAD authentication to serve app installer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have a windows app installer that I need to make available to my company's users outside of the firewall.

The installer handles initial installation as well as updates. So once installed, the app will access the same URL location to check for updates.

I'm considering using Azure Blob storage, but also need to ensure only users from our Azure Active Directory can access the files.

I've done some searches, but get conflicting and confusing information as this is not my area of expertise.

How do you properly configure Azure Blob storage to only serve files to my company's authenticated AAD users? That is, so they can go to a URL in their browser and download the EXE file, and my app can access the URL to check for updates?

Comment: Try to follow this guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/vignettes/aad.html